# Command "stringa.replaceAll("*", stringb); causes an error

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to replace an asterisk in my first string with the second string. For example, if string a is "d*g" and string b is "in", when I run my code string a should become "ding". However, when I run it I get this message:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main5.java:404)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

The exact code segment is as follows.

```
String a = scan.nextLine();
String b = scan.nextLine();

a = a.replaceAll("*", b);
System.out.println(a);
```

Is there any way to make this code function as intended?

Answer (score 3):

You are supplying a regular expression `"*"` to `replaceAll`, and `*` has special meaning.

To supply a literal `*`, you must escape the `*` with a backslash character, which itself needs to be escaped in Java.

```
a = a.replaceAll("\\*", b);
```

Comment: Or you could just replace `replaceAll` with `replace` and not use regular expressions when they aren't needed or wanted. As a bonus, your code would run (very slightly) faster, too.

Comment: @DavidConrad, are you sure `replace` is any faster than `replaceAll`?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't compile the string to a regex, and that must take some time, no?

Comment: In the version I looked at the only difference is that one passes the `LITERAL` flag to `Pattern.compile` and the other doesn't.  I'm not sure if compiling with the flag is any quicker.

Answer (score 1):

The method [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression as the first parameter. In order to use `*` in a regex you have to escape it. However, it appears like you really wanted [`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) like

```
String stringa = "d*g";
String stringb = stringa.replace("*", "in");
System.out.println(stringb);
```

Or, escape the `*` like

```
String stringc = stringa.replaceAll("\\*", "in");
System.out.println(stringc);
```

The output of both is your requested `ding`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method:

```
stringa.replace("*", stringb);
```

Which replaces all instances of the first string with the second string. The [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method, on the other hand, uses regular expressions, and `"*"` by itself is not a regular expression since the asterisk character is a modifier that means "the previous thing, repeated zero or more times".